# OperationCanceledException being thrown in Adam Freeman's Pro Parallel Programming in C#'s examples. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

When running in a Console application under Visual Studio 2012 Listing_07 of Adam Freeman's Pro .NET 4 Parallel Programming in C#, I get an exception when I try to cancel the task. To me there seems to be no big mistery as to the why of this, as we're throwing (or so it seems) a `OperationCanceledException` when a cancellation attempt is detected in the task.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? The problem is arising in basically all his task cancellation examples! I can only assume something in the Task Library was changed since the book came to the stores (2010) ?

```
// create the cancellation token source
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource
    = new CancellationTokenSource();

// create the cancellation token
CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

// create the task
Task task = new Task(() => {
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++) {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) {
            Console.WriteLine("Task cancel detected");
            throw new OperationCanceledException(token);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Int value {0}", i);
        }
    }
}, token);

// wait for input before we start the task
Console.WriteLine("Press enter to start task");
Console.WriteLine("Press enter again to cancel task");
Console.ReadLine();

// start the task
task.Start();

// read a line from the console.
Console.ReadLine();

// cancel the task
Console.WriteLine("Cancelling task");
tokenSource.Cancel();

// wait for input before exiting
Console.WriteLine("Main method complete. Press enter to finish.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What exception are you getting apart from OperationCanceled?

Comment: You are throwing that exception, why are you surprised you see it?  Use Task.Wait to get the exception at a predictable place in your code.

Comment: @marc_s : It is an `OperationCanceledException`, not an `OperationCancelledException`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is caught by the TPL, and the Task is put into the Canceled state. So, while you will see the exception (if you have exceptions turned on in the debugger), it will be handled.

As leon mentioned, you should be using the `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` method, rather than explicitly doing the check + throw yourself.

This page gives good details on cancellation of Tasks:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx

Comment: Does that mean that one cannot debug code with TPL? Or just that I have to take that exception out of the debugger?

Comment: You can still debug.  Like you said you can turn off that exception, or when you hit the exception you should be able to continue to run (F5) from that point (can you not?).

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that Visual Studio allowed you to continue your program after an exception had been thrown.

Answer (score 1):

There is no try catch to silence the exception. It is just thrown when you press enter twice.
Isn't it made to behave this way? Wrap it in a try 'n catch and it should be graceful.

```
                try
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
                    {
                        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Task cancel detected");
                            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Int value {0}", i);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(OperationCanceledException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task cancelled via token!");
                }
```

There's also that convenient CancelletionToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() method you could use to catch.

Comment: I am led to believe that if there was an uncatched exception to bethrown up to the surface, this wouldn't be the suggested method to accomplish task-cancellation in the book.

Comment: :-) Since the code is throwing a **new** OperationCancelledException, this will be unhandled unless you wrap it either in the code as I suggested or somewhere up in the flow hierarchy. However, if you DO use the cancellation token's ThrowIfCancellationRequested method then it will be treated gracefully as a means to accomplish task cancellation. My code was just to write to the console that the Task was cancelled via the token so that you can observe it.